# Обновление фрейма в selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

На странице есть фрейм с формами ввода.
Разворачиваю дерево ДП.Адреса, жду, ищу строку "Регион", при клике получаю ошибку.

```
 r = self.driver.find_element_by_id('tree#16.123#         69#Level#Text#mi')
 r.click()

selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
```

Если обернуть в WebdriverWait(), получаю ошибку timeout.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь обновить фрейм после раскрытия дерева (может из-за этого webdriver не видит элемент). тоже получаю ошибку:

```
self.driver.execute_script('document.getElementById("ITSFRAME1").contentWindow.location.reload()')

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Cannot read property 'contentWindow' of null
```

Как правильно обновить данные во фрейме?

Comment: Элемент, на который вы кликаете находится в прямой видимости? или для его видимости нужно скроллить?

Comment: @danilshik нужно скролить по форме вниз

Comment: поэтому он и не видит. Хоть во время клика, он скроллится к объекту, но иногда возникает такая проблема. Поэтому всегда перед кликом сами проскрольте к объекту

Comment: def scrolling_object(object):
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(object).perform();

Comment: @danilshik написал так
actionChains = ActionChains(self.driver)        actionChains.move_to_element(self.driver.find_element_by_id(id)).perform()
ошибки нет, но и скролла к элементу не произошло, если дальше продолжить find и click, то снова ошибка not visible

Comment: перед началом скроллинга вам нужно переключиться на этот фрейм